# Test Framework for EJB and CDI

Tags: java, testing, jboss, ejb, cdi

I'm looking for an alternative to Arquillian framework. The main problem with it was to create the Shrinkwrap Archives (mainly because of cyclic dependencies).
Do you know other frameworks which supports Context Dependency Injection and EJB Test using JBoss as a Server?

Comment: You should take a look at CDI-Unit to test both EJB and CDI : http://jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/#ejb .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Pax Exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM4/Pax+Exam). It supports WildFly and JBoss 7+ as well as other Java EE or OSGi environments.